# Netbeans - Deployment error - Weblogic

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic12c

I have a dynamic webproject in netbeans. There is two pc where we're developing the project. We cloned the project by git to another pc and after pressing 'clean and build' netbeans build is succesfull but it can't be deployed to weblogic. If i try to deploy the war file manually to weblogic from the wl console it works properly and deploy finsh without any errors. Netbeans shows this is netbeans log:

```
ant -f C:\\Myapp\\Myapp -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Myapp\\Myapp  run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
xjc-typedef-target:
jaxb-code-generation:
files are up to date
files are up to date
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Checking data source definitions for missing JDBC drivers...
JDBC driver deployment completed.
C:\Myapp\Myapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1130: Deployment error.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I checked but there isn't any other error message in weblogic log.

The relevant part of the build-impl.xml is the following:

```
  <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>
```

On the 'master' pc we can deploy from netbeans also.

Does anyone know where I might look to get relevant information to debug this?
Thank you!

Comment: *"Does anybody have any idea about how to solve this? "* without any hint of an error to go on? Before you can solve something you need to know what's wrong. You're not at that stage yet to be asking this question. A more prudent question would be: does anyone know where I might look to get relevant information to debug this?

Comment: You are right! sorry! i edited my question.. :)

Comment: There isn't anything in the server log..

Comment: I'd post the content of said log (after a failed deploy through Netbeans) anyway to prove that. There might be a hint in there that gives an idea where to look. Sometimes an error comes with a very visible stacktrace, and sometimes an error is sneakily hidden within a single line.

Comment: The weblogic log is full empty.

Comment: Okay, that would trigger me to suspect the server isn't setup properly in Netbeans itself. If only deployment fails then you'd get minimal startup blurb in the logs, if they stay empty then the process fails before deployment